# c# Unable to connect to a member of the replica set matching the read preference Primary

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

Ok I have two nodes setup with a replicaset on a linux server.

In the c# application using 1.8.1.20 driver I have

```
client = new MongoClient("mongodb://54.244.162.21,54.234.244.182/rs0?connect=replicaset;replicaSet=rs0;slaveOk=true;readPreference=primaryPreferred");
```

-When I connect with mongo to each node both master and slave the updates and find statements work properly.

-When I try to bring down any node either the primary or secondary I get:
Unable to connect to a member of the replica set matching the read preference Primary

-When both nodes are up I get no error and everything works fine.

-I have tried to change the readPreference to every possible value because I want to see how the redundancy works.

Am I getting something wrong.  I am assuming that you should be able to connect to either one and at least get reads working.  The following code is what I have that the exception occurs on obviously when the connection is first established.

```
        server = client.GetServer();

        foreach (string db in server.GetDatabaseNames())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(db);
        }
```

Comment: do you only have two members in your replica set?  if so if one is brought down the other won't be able to be a primary and you won't be able to make any writes.  See documentation of replica sets - you need to add a third node - either regular data node or just an arbiter.

Comment: by the way, you are not connecting to individual node with the code you posted, you are connecting to a named replica set and the host:port is only used in discovery of the rest of the replica set.

Comment: I understand that writes don't work until an election occurs. But shouldn't reads work at least. Shouldn't the connection string I used get the valid hosts by discovering them but then look for a node that is up to read from. I would hope that if a primary is down until an election occurs reads are still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some database commands can only run on the primary.  If you issue one while connecting to a replica set which has no primary then you get this error.

The command in this case is server.GetDatabaseNames() - it's possible that it was an oversight that it is not able to run this command on the secondary, but for the moment that is the case.

I'm going to check with the folks who maintain MongoDB drivers and see if this command should be allowed on a secondary or not.

For your example, I think you will find that if your program connected and then issued read queries, then it would work fine.

Comment: We also need better error messaging for this.  I have created a JIRA ticket for this here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-730.

Comment: All this is great. You guys put me in the right direction as I did not know if this is by design. My initial question went unanswered. The question was whether you can read from a secondary if a primary was down (and no other secondary was elected -- two node scenario or three node scenario where two nodes fail and one secondary is left). After you guys gave me a heads up that getdatabasenames() does not work without a primary I tried to read from a collection which did work. So for anyone out there with this very important question. Yes reads are possible without a primary. Again thanks guys.

Comment: Actually, my last sentence says this explicitly :)   - issue a read query and it should work fine (on the secondary).

Comment: Sorry about that for some reason I read everything carefully except for the last line.

Comment: Is there a list of commands that can only be run on the primary?